# Can I generate a linq expression dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've currently got a piece of Linq that looks something like this ;

```
List<dynamic> childrenToBeRemoved = this.ItemsSource.Where(o => o.ParentID == "1234").ToList();
```

where ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection of dynamics.

This works fine, but the problem I've got is that the ParentID is a property that can vary. E.g. it could be named ParentPkey or ParentKey etc.

Can I create an expression where I can specify the property that I want to use in my comparison?

I've tried using dynamic linq but it doesn't work using a collection of dynamics, works fine with a collection of pocos.

Thanks...

Comment: why could the condition vary? ... why not make a `Func<TItem, bool>` which you then inject as `this.ItemSource.Where(myFunc)` instead of making the parameter itself dynamic (it's still possible, but the overhead in expressions and generics is may be not worth it)?

Comment: [yes, you can](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) but it kinda feels like you are using a dynamic shotgun to kill a static fly.

Comment: The condition is the same but the property I'm using in that expression could change, I'm taking a look a building a condition using the expression tree builder, but your correct it seems like a massive hammer and a very small nail. Given that the property can vary how would the first Func<Titem,bool> approach look like ?

Comment: why is the property varying?! (btw - if the property differs, the condition itself differs either!)

Comment: @Bendy see my answer on how you could use the `Func<TItem, bool>`-approach

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair, could you flesh this one out for me ? I'm having problem visualising it? thanks...

Comment: @Bendy ... see my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/10497938/57508

Answer (score 6):

why make the implementation itself dynamic? you could simply do a dynamic invocation!

```
IEnumerable<MyItem> result;
if (condition1)
{
    result = this.Items.Where(arg => arg.ProductId == "123");
}
else if (condition2)
{
    result = this.Items.Where(arg => arg.ProductPK == "123");
}
```

or

```
Func<Item, bool> predicate;
if (condition1)
{
    predicate = item => item.ProductId == "123";
}
else if (condition2)
{
    predicate = item => item.ProductPK == "123";
}
var result = this.Items.Where(predicate);
```

Sooo ... I believe you should tell us more about your actual problem - I do not see any current need to implement sth - so, I believe your requirement is ill-defined!

Answer (score 6):

it should not matter if query is dynamic linq or not

```
Expression<Func<Entity, int>> predicate = x => x.Id == myvalue;
from entity in _context.Entities.Where(predicate)
select entity;
```

Check out PredicateBuilder of LinkKit @ http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx
there are enough examples there as well

Responsibility of translation of an expression to corresponding sql lies with the linq provider, so make sure the provider you are using supports the relevant aspects

Answer (score 0):

Put you linq expression into a function, and pass in this property as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of your items, you can use reflection :

```
PropertyInfo parentProp = itemType.GetProperty("ParentKey or whatever");
List<dynamic> childrenToBeRemoved = this.ItemsSource.Where(o => Equals("1234", parentProp.GetValue(o, null))).ToList();
```

Comment: is this type-safe? what if the property is not typeof `System.String`?

Comment: Right, it won't even compile, I corrected for a more robust use of Equals

Comment: and how could you compare against `null`? :) ... why not use `Equals()` (static implementation on `System.Object`)? The main problem you'll get in this scenario is, that you would have to get all the records to your domain, as this comparison cannot be translated to EF or sth alike ...

Comment: The convention is to return false for Equals(null), which is the case for the string.Equals. So no problem with that.

Comment: argl ... `this.ItemsSource.Where(o => null.Equals(o.foo))` ... :) ... you should use `this.ItemsSource.Where(o => Equals(null, o.foo))` instead