# Dynamic where clause using Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to do a filter "where" on the not selected elements and are not in the ViewModel

**this is that I have:**

```
var UserQuery = (from u in db.USER
                join c in db.CONSULT on u.IdUser equals c.IdUser
                select new UserSexViewModel {  IdUser= c.IdUser, UserSex=u.Sex}).Distinct();
```

I want to filter later the variable `UserQuery` by any property belonging to the object CONSULT or object USER

for example, filter later by:

```
CONSULT.TypeConsul, 
CONSULT.DateCreation,
USER.Name,
USER.Age, and many more...
```

**something like this:**

```
UserQuery.Where(q=>q.CONSULT.TypeConsul==2) or UserQuery.Where(q=>q.USER.Age>16)
```

How I can do this?

Comment: essentially what you are trying to do is build criteria, does not require Linq Dynamic query library, all you need to do is build the expression qualifier --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497801/can-i-generate-a-linq-expression-dynamically-in-c/10498056#10498056

Answer (score 0):

the LINQ Dynamic Query Library will help you.

please refer to  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I did not find helpful, please help

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserQuery = (from u in db.USER
                join c in db.CONSULT on u.IdUser equals c.IdUser
                select new UserSexViewModel {  IdUser= c.IdUser, UserSex=u.Sex}).Distinct();
```

//pseudo code

```
var specification = PredicateBuilder.True<Consult>();//default: build from this
specification = PredicateBuilder.And(specification, x => x.TypeConsult == 2); 
var additionalCriterias = ...;
specification = additionalCriterias == null || additionalCriterias.Length == 0 
                  ? specification 
                  : GetComposedSpecification(additionalCriterias);

var users = UserQuery.Where(specification).ToList()
```

predicateBuilder @ http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx with many more examples